# how to create 2 stars using hcipy package of python?

Tags: python

cant seem to create one

i tried using fraunhofer propagation but it was not creating it properly. Tried to change the wavefront to get the required data but still was not able to do it. so how should I proceed to do this ???

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.